# AngularJS - Update selected options for multiple select

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to make a simple "autocomplete". Enter keyword into input and select the result. Then the selected items will be shown. I'm currently stucking in how to change the hidden `select` and show selected items. Could you help me?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="search" ng-model="query">
    <ul ng-repeat="game in games | filter:query" ng-show="query.length >= 2 && (games | filter:query).length">
        <li><a ng-click="selectGame(game.id)">{{ game.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <select multiple name="games" style="display:none;" ng-options="game.id as game.name for game in games"></select>

    <ul class="selected-games">
        <li>{{ game.name }} - {{ game.year }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/ajax/all/games/').success(function(data){
        $scope.games = data;
    });

    $scope.selectGame = function() {}; //?
}
//MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

// JSON data from URL
var games = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Halo', 'year': '2005'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Final Fantasy', 'year': '2008'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Guitar Heroes', 'year': '2008'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Warcraft', 'year': '2003'},
    {'id': 5, 'name': 'Starcraft II', 'year': '2010'},
    {'id': 6, 'name': 'Fifa 12', 'year': '2012'},
];
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create a plunker with your example?

Comment: @matys84pl: I pasted the code at http://jsfiddle.net/anhtran/fAmEs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to understand what your desired result is, but check out my updates here: http://jsfiddle.net/rS6Hz/1/. I added a new variable to the `scope`, an array called selectedGames and implemented the ng-click by adding to that array.

```
$scope.selectedGames = [];

$scope.selectGame = function(game) {
    $scope.selectedGames.push(game);        
};
```

Then, in the display, you have to add an `ng-model` to the `select` for it to do anything (as far as I can tell) and the `ul` of `selected-games` needs an `ng-repeater` to loop over the `selectedGames`

```
<select multiple name="games" ng-model="something" ng-options="game.id as game.name for game in selectedGames"></select>

<h1>Selected Games</h1>
<ul class="selected-games">
    <li ng-repeat="game in selectedGames">{{ game.name }} - {{ game.year }}</li>
</ul>
```

(I removed the `display: none;` on the `select` in order to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, without using a separate variable:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ag9r/

Basically:

```
 <ul class="selected-games">
        <li ng-repeat='game in games | filter:{selected:true}'>{{ game.name }} - {{ game.year }}</li>
 </ul>
```

I believe it is a cleaner solution than the accepted one